# how to filter a grid based on codtions and than bind the grid using xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have one text box and a button and a grid

```
textbox ID-->Client side---------------->txtFirstName
button Name-->Client side--------------->btnSearch
Grid id-->Client side------------------->gvContactUS
```

On click of button Search i am trying to search a record which i have entered in textbox whose name is is their in the xml file and will show that in the grid

my xml file is :Contact.xml

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <HeaderDetailID>1</HeaderDetailID>
        <FirstName>Basant</FirstName>
        <LastName>Gera</LastName>
        <EmployeeID>0012</EmployeeID>
        <Department>SD</Department>
        <Postion>Programmer</Postion>
        <Application>P and  L - Joint Cost***BI_AP_KL_COST</Application>
        <Filter>Africa_ww_READ</Filter>
        <AreaorCountryorStation>India</AreaorCountryorStation>
        <NetworkDomain>.Net</NetworkDomain>
        <Action>
          Modification
        </Action>
        <NameOfController>Nitin</NameOfController>
      </CD>
    </CATALOG>
```

I am trying to filter only 1 record which is their into the grid.

But i am getting the full grid.

Code as follows:

```
     protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 string FilepathContact;
        string FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        FilepathContact = Server.MapPath("~/Contact.xml");
        DataSet dsdata = new DataSet();
        dsdata.ReadXml(FilepathContact);
    }

if (dsdata.Tables["CD"].Rows.Count != 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < dsdata.Tables["CD"].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            if (Convert.ToString(dsdata.Tables["CD"].Rows[i]["FirstName"]) == Convert.ToString(FirstName))
            {
                gvContactUS.DataSource = dsdata;
                gvContactUS.DataBind();
            }

        }
    }
```

}

Now I am getting all the records which is their in my grid.
How do i find the element and search if its their than bind the grid only with that record which is their in data set.

I am using .net Framework 2.0 so LINQ dont work her.

Comment: DataRow row = dsdata.Tables["CD"].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("FirstName") == "Basant").FirstOrDefault();

Comment: i got the solution thanks